# Google calendar using php does not show shared calendar list

Tags: php

I am using JSON key file authorization for getting calendars list so i can enter new calendar event.
The problem is that at specific google account i am getting calendar list and when following same instruction on different google account the list is empty.

This is the code:

```
require_once 'vendor//autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $credenential);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName("Quickstart");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
$startDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start);
$endDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end);
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $title_event,
  'location' => $where_event,
  'description' => $content_event,
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => rawurldecode($start)
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => rawurldecode($end)
  )
));

foreach($calendarList as $item) {
    if ( strcasecmp( $item['summary'], $google_email ) == 0 ){
      $calendarId = $item['id'];
    }
}
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```